# What is the best format/compatibility to save a PSD file if needing to open it in GIMP in Mac OS X?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp

The standard PSD I have is being displayed incorrectly in GIMP. Colours are missing etc...

I have access to PhotoShop. Which method should I use to save the file under PhotoShop to maximise compatibility with GIMP?

Comment: Have you checked the "Maximize Compatibility" option when saving in Photoshop?

Comment: I didn't see that option... I'll have a hunt for it.

Comment: It ought to prompt you every time you save a PSD dile...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what all your PSD has, you may be able to get away with `.tiff`. My experience tells me GIMP has some issues with multiple complex layers and text and all that jazz, but good luck.

To maximize compatibility it's *Edit > Preferences > File Handling*. It will differ slightly depending on your version. Here's a screenshot:

[image: maximizing compatibility in Photoshop]

Comment: +1 great answer - no freehand circles? :P